# Describe qualitatively the amount of current passing through resistor if the source oscillated at low frequency?

Tags: current, resistors, frequency, high-frequency

I am stuck on lab question 3. I do not know how to determine the current crossing the resistor for oscillating current at varying frequencies.

Help is greatly appreciated

[image: The circuit]

Comment: What _do_ you understand about this circuit? Which components behave differently for high and low frequencies? How is the current through the resistor related to the current through the capacitor and the current from the supply?

Comment: Figure 4 is certainly an odd "Capacitive high-pass filter".

Answer (score 1):

This a [current divider](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current_divider#General_case) so the *greater* current is through the *lesser* impedance.

The resistor impedance is constant with frequency.  However, the (magnitude of the) capacitor impedance varies with (angular) frequency as

$$|Z_C| = \dfrac{1}{\omega C} $$

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

If the frequency is high, meaning current doesn't flow for very long in either direction, the capacitor will suck it up, in the sense that in a short amount of time it can't get charged much before the accumulated charge is removed again.  So not much voltage can develop and therefore little current flows through the resistor (the current through resistor follows ohm's law: I=V/R).  You could say that the cap will shunt high frequency signals.

But if the frequency is low, the cap can develop more voltage in each half-cycle, and more current will flow through the resistor.  You could say that a cap looks like an open circuit at low frequencies.

What constitutes high/low frequency in this case depends on the values of R and C.  The currents will have equal amplitude when R = 1/wC, so you could consider frequencies above one order of magnitude higher than 1/RC as high, and frequencies below one order of magnitude lower than 1/RC as low.